# Is there a way to make the particle system spread a little as it moves along a force field?

Tags: animation, particles

I'm working on an animation project where I have to animate certain set of particles to be pushed out of an exhaust and then expand/spread apart a little to show the flow of air. I cannot however, find a way to make this possible.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Update:

if you are using a curve guide, you could also give it a bit of falloff power:

[image]

result:

left: without falloff, right: with 0.2 falloff

[image]

---

You can just add a turbulence force field and play with the strength.

Here are some examples with different strength of the turbulence field and the same emitter parameters.

[image]

Comment: I'm already using a curve for forcefield, can I still use the same method ?

Comment: AFAIK yes...the force fields are additive....